# Bootstrap - Modal isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I Have the modal set like this

```
<body>
<div class="modal fade" id="pageopen" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    x
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    This Modal title
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Add some text here
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
</div>

<button onclick="showModal('http://www.google.co.id/')">Show Modal</button>

</body>
```

I've added the latest jquery, bootstrap js and css for only the modal plugin.
The problem I have is that the modal backdrop shows, however the modal header body and etc isn't showing up.

[My Code](http://jsfiddle.net/godheaper/y5bLm874/2/)

Please provide solution, thank you

Comment: How is the button linked to the modal?
Pls go to http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals and look how the `<button>` is made to be refered to the correct modal.
There is also written, what you have to do when loading iframes.
`<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>` this is what your button or link should look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Javascript Code is wrong, to open a Bootstrap 3 Modal you should use:

```
$('#pageopen').modal({
        show: true
});
```

If you want to load an external Page, you can set the url here:

```
$('#pageopen').modal({
    show: true,
    remote: 'http://www.example.com'
});
```

And better use the jQuery click Function instead of "onClick".

Comment: Ah, thank you. This is just what I need.
BTW, the problem in my page is because I loaded 2 separate css for the bootstrap, so the modal class overlapped with each other and just ruined the modal styling. anyway thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `showModal` function isn't found by `onclick`, please stop using onclick in your html forever. That has never been a good practice.
Instead of this set an ID for button and use the `.click` function in JQuery:

```
<button id="showModal">Show Modal</button>

$("#showModal").click(function(){
    $('#pageopen').modal();
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y5bLm874/13/)**

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I will remember to not use html events next time.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, never mind. I have separate js and css for the same bootstrap component so it overlapped over each other.

**Tip for bootstrap :**
Always load only one js file and one css file for bootstrap.
If you're like me that want's only part of the bootstrap instead of all the package, (e.g: modal, transition and carousel), then make it as one js and css from getbootstrap